# How can we implement label based acces control(LBAC) in marklogic

Tags: database, marklogic, nosql

Currently implementation of role based access control (RBAC) and attribute based access control (ABAC) is provided for marklogic, But I couldn't find how LBAC is implemented in marklogic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MarkLogic does not have "Rows and Columns", so LBAC may not make sense.

However, if you consider that standard modelling in MarkLogic suggests that a single document is equivalent to a single row of a table, you could then consider this the same idea of a database 'object' in IBM. Then I would say that URI permissions on a single document is similar.

However, sit tight until MarkLogic 9 (Just 'around the corner', I believe). In this release, you have element-level security - security attached to particular elements/attributes based on xPath expressions. It may match your use-case (which of course, depends on how your data is modelled)

Internally, we have extensively tested the feature and it works wonderfully for security on subsets of a document. It is already mentioned publicly here:
http://www.marklogic.com/press-releases/marklogic-9-transforms-database-market/